# RegExp to match fraction and decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to perform regex to match a fraction and decimals.
The user will input a decimal or fraction eg., 22, 11, 1/4, 15 1/2, 2.5, 55.3  etc.

I had tried like this but it not allowing me for 15 1/4

my Regex..

```
^[0-9]*([.|/][1-9]+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /\d+([\s\.\/]\d)*/g;
const str = `22, 11, 1/4, 15 1/2, 2.5, 55.3`;

const result = str.match(regex);
console.log( result );
```